# Android 8 (Oreo) emulator binaries

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source, android-8.0-oreo

I'm trying to build Android 8 (Oreo) and run the emulator for the *aosp_arm64-eng* build.
When I built it and run the command emulator, it starts but the screen is blank. Logcat shows me some native exception due to the lack of opengl libraries.

After some research, I'm pretty sure I need the vendor images (or binary drivers) for the emulator (probably named mini-arm64), as for physical devices (https://developers.google.com/android/drivers).

Where can I find them?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, opengl drivers from real devices won't work. The emulator needs some special drivers in order to render on the host side. You can try to extract the swiftshader somewhere, and put into the image. Then run emulator with -gpu guest option.